# Ruby TCPServer fails to work sometimes

Tags: ruby, sockets, rspec, server, tcpserver

I've implemented a very simple kind of server in Ruby, using `TCPServer`. I have a `Server` class with `serve` method:

```
def serve
    # Do the actual serving in a child process
    @pid = fork do
      # Trap signal sent by #stop or by pressing ^C
      Signal.trap('INT') { exit }

      # Create a new server on port 2835 (1 ounce = 28.35 grams)
      server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2835)
      @logger.info 'Listening on http://localhost:2835...'

      loop do
        socket = server.accept
        request_line = socket.gets

        @logger.info "* #{request_line}"

        socket.print "message"

        socket.close
      end
    end
  end
```

and a `stop` method:

```
def stop
    @logger.info 'Shutting down'
    Process.kill('INT', @pid)
    Process.wait
    @pid = nil
end
```

I run my server from the command line, using:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  server = Server.new
  server.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  server.logger.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg| "#{msg}\n" }
  begin
    server.serve
    Process.wait
  rescue Interrupt
    server.stop
  end
end
```

The problem is that, sometimes, when I do `ruby server.rb` from my terminal, the server starts, but when I try to make a request on `localhost:2835`, it fails. Only after several requests it starts serving some pages. In other cases, I need to stop/start the server again for it to properly serve pages. Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong? I find this very weird...

The same things applies to my specs: I have some specs defined, and some Capybara specs. Before each test I create a server and start it and after each test I stop the server. And the problem persists: tests sometimes pass, sometimes fail because the requested page could not be found.

Is there something fishy going on with my `fork`ing?

Would appreciate any answer because I have no more place to look...

Comment: Your code works reliably when I run it. How are you making requests to your server? I am using `nc`.

Comment: The classic way: opening the browser at `localhost:2835`. And in tests, the 'classic' Capybara way, with `visit 'localhost:2833'`.

Comment: That's your problem. If you want to visit `localhost:2835` in your browser, you have to implement an HTTP server. The code you posted isn't a HTTP server.

Comment: Why wouldn't my code stand for an HTTP server?

Comment: See my answer, there is a link in it which I think will resolve your confusion

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not an HTTP server. It is a TCP server that sends the string "message" over the socket after receiving a newline.

The reason that your code isn't a valid HTTP server is that it doesn't conform to the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). One of the many requirements of the HTTP protocol is that the server respond with a message of the form

```
HTTP/1.1 <code> <reason>
```

Where `<code>` is a number and `<reason>` is a human-readable "status", like "OK" or "Server Error" or something along those lines. The string `message` obviously does not conform to this requirement.

Here is a simple introduction to how you might build a HTTP server in ruby: https://practicingruby.com/articles/implementing-an-http-file-server

Comment: I understand your point now. I have an HTTP server, I have just trimmed my code so that the question remains readable. Still, the fact that **sometimes** I manage to successfully serve a page, should lead to the fact that the server is implemented properly. If it hadn't been, I should have received some error **each** time. After digging deeper, I noticed that only Firefox has this issue; with Chrome (and Selenium's Chrome driver in Capybara) I couldn't reproduce this issue, no matter how many times I loaded a page/ran the tests. Maybe this should be some sort of clue?

Comment: Well, I can confirm without a doubt that there isn't anything wrong with the code in your question. If you are having problems with your actual code, it means that there is a problem in that which is not present in this code.

Comment: What browser have you used for testing the above code?

Comment: When I tested your code, I didn't use a web browser, because I wasn't aware that you were trying to make a HTTP server. I used netcat.

Comment: Okay. So probably there is an issue with Firefox, or at least, _my_ Firefox. Because other methods work as expected. Will have to figure out what could be the problem with Firefox, though.